# passing slices in a nested struct into Revel template in Go

Tags: go, struct, slice, revel

I'm trying to pass off slices in a nested struct to a Revel template, but I get the error:

7: executing "App/Index.html" at <.data.company>: company is an unexported field of struct type interface {}

```
CONTROLLER
type company struct {
    Tradetotals float64
    Totals      float64
    CostCount   string
    TraderCount string
}

type alldata struct {
    company []company
}



func (c App) Index() revel.Result {
    //etc
    //etc
    //etc

    return c.Render(data)
}

INDEX
{{range $count, $company := .data.company}}
    <div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sq-lg btn-danger" name="333" value="2-50000">
            <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x"></i><br/>
            Demo Danger <br>Button
    </button>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sq-lg btn-success">
            <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x"></i>
            US: {{$company.Tradetotals}}<br>{{$company.Totals}}<br>{{$company.Totals}} {{$company.CostCount}}

    </button>
    </div>
{{end}}
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your struct. When executing a template, you only have access to the exported fields of your structs.

If you try to access an unexported one, you'll receive an error.
It should solve your issue.

```
type alldata struct {
    Company []company
}
```